# Executing bash via Java process builder

Tags: java

I'm trying to execute a script via JAVA code, but it's not being executed. I tried `execute()` of `Process` class but later switched to `ProcessBuilder` after some searching hoping to make this work. But the script's not getting executed.

**JAVA Code:**

```
String fileName = "pkgdiff.sh";
File file = new File(fileName);
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", fileName);
builder.directory(file.getParentFile());
Process process = builder.start();
process.waitFor();
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String line = "";                       
while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
    output.append(line + "\n");
}
LOGGER.info("### Script Execution result --> " + fileName+"-->" + output);
```

**Script file:**

```
#!/bin/sh
.. rest of the content
```

Comment: What do you expect the code to do and what does it actually?

Comment: `I'm trying to execute a script via JAVA code` and it's not getting executed.

Comment: Do the user that executes the java process has security permissions to do so? Does the script have permission to be executed?

Comment: @JorgeCampos yes I have the permission. I can execute it fine via the terminal

Comment: If i replace /bin/sh with `echo` it's working fine

Comment: What is `fileName`? Please create a [mcve].

Comment: have you tried replacing /bin/sh with whatever filename is?

Answer (score 1):

How much output is the script producing? You should be processing its output *before* you call `waitFor()`, otherwise the process might block if it fills up its output buffer.

From the [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html):

> Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess to block, or even deadlock.

Comment: It's exactly 30 lines and each line would take about 1-2 seconds to print

Comment: So where am I supposed to put the `waitFor()`? before the logger print?

Comment: Yes, before the log message. Or after, since you're not checking the exit code. The main thing not to call it until `reader.readLine()` returns null.

Comment: Thanks and I've added the same. Still nothing. I've no clue what I'm missing. Since if I replace /bin/sh with echo it's working fine :/

Comment: @MageshKumaar Regardless of how much output a process might produce, `waitFor` will *wait for the process to finish,* so you should never call that method until you are done interacting with the process.